# Why does Visual Studio 2013 not know the definition of a property I defined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I declared an interface like this:

```
interface IConfigAdmin {
    contentCreatedBy: number;
}
```

Here I am using it:

```
    private getDefaultAdminConfigs = (): IConfigAdmin => {
        return {
            contentCreatedBy: null
        };
    }
```

If I try to set this to [] instead of null it gives an error as I would expect but 
why is it that when I hover over contentCreatedBy in VS2013 that it says this is 
a (property) contentCreatedBy: any

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by casting it to `IConfigAdmin` first. This way you get autocompletion to while typing.
I guess it could have inferred the type because of the return statement but I'm not sure.

```
return <IConfigAdmin> { }
```

See playground: [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IConfigAdmin%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20contentCreatedBy%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20class%20t%20%7B%0D%0A%20%09private%20getDefaultAdminConfigs%20%3D%20()%3A%20IConfigAdmin%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3CIConfigAdmin%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09contentCreatedBy%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%09%7D%0D%0A%20%7D)

Comment: I tried this but it still did not work. I also tried var config: IConfigAdmin = { xxxx }.  Still did not work and shows any although if I try to enter anything that's not a null or number it does complain.

Comment: It works in the playground as you are setting it to a number. But if you set it to null it does not know it's a number.